# Open (but not closed) subgroups of $GL_n$

Tags: lie-groups, examples-counterexamples

The book I am currently reading states:

"...as we will see later, non-closed subgroups [of $GL_n(\mathbb K)$] are not necessarily manifolds."

Prompted me to think about open subgroups of $GL_n$:

Is there an example of an open but not closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb K)$ where $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H\}$?

Comment: Non-closed and open are different things.

Comment: Indeed sets are not doors. They can be open, closed, both or neither.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Oh, I ignored the "necessarily". Of course, not necessarily means they may well be manifolds. So this does not exclude open sets.

Comment: Actually the only open subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ that I can think of is the set of all matrices with positive determinant, which is also closed as a subset of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Would the set of matrices with determinant $\in (0,1)$ not be an open subgroup?

Comment: Nope. It's not closed under inversion. A matrix with determinant 1/2 would have inverse with determinant 2.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Oops, true.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I edited my question to include the results of our discussion in these comments.

Comment: I conjecture the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

There are no such examples, for any Lie group $G$.

For, suppose $H$ is an open subset of a Lie group $G$.  Because $H$ is open in $G$, $T_e H = T_e G$, so $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{g}$.  Using the fact that a connected Lie subgroup of $G$ is completeley determined by its Lie algebra, this implies that the identity component of $H$ and $G$, denoted, $H^0$ and $G^0$, are equal.

It follows easily that if $H$ intersects a component $G'$ of $G$, then $G'\subseteq H$:  Suppose $h\in G'\cap H$ and suppose $g\in G'$.  Then $h^{-1}g\in G^0 = H^0$, so $h^{-1} g = h'$ for some $h'\in H^0$.  Thus, $g = hh'\in H$.

It follows from this that $H$ is a union of components of $G$.  In particular, $H$ is closed in $G$.

Comment: The subgroup of $Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices with positive determinant is a proper open subset of $Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$.  The other general linear groups (for $K\in\{ \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}\}$) are connected, so admit no proper open subgroups.

Comment: Ah of course. I should have thought about using the Lie algebra.

Comment: May I asked another related question? I know that an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is a manifold. Is a closed subset also a manifold?

Comment: Also, if I assume that $T_e$ means the tangent space at $e$, is it a general result that if $H$ is an open subset of a Lie group then the tangent spaces at the identity are equal?

Comment: @learner:  Closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are generally not manifolds (even allowing boundary).  For example, the union of the two coordinate axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed, but the origin is not a manifold point.  Also, yes, $T_e$ means the tangent space at $e$.  It's generally true that for any two manifolds $M$ and $N$, if $M$ is an open subset of $N$, then their tangent spaces agree at every point they have in common.  (This is not too hard to prove, using the derivatives-of-curves notion of tangent space)