# Open subgroups of $Gl_n$ which are not closed.

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064347/340973) where the OP asks if there are open subgroups of $Gl_n$ that are not closed. The answer uses Lie algebras but I don't understand why. Isn't any open subgroup of a topological group closed and like explained in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226847/340973). It seems there is something I am missing? Why take the trouble consider Lie-algebras?

Comment: That question is about **subgroups**, not about **subsets**.

Comment: Hello. I don't get it.

Comment: The title of this question of yours is “Open subsets of $Gl_n$ which are not closed”, but that other question is about *subgroups*, not about *subsets*. Don't you see a difference?

Comment: I did a mistake in the title. I edited

Comment: Then all that I can say is that there is no need to mention Lie algebras here.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Every open subgroup of every topological group is closed. This is because its complement is the union of its nontrivial coset; each coset is open (as the image of the subgroup under a shift, which is a homeomorphism), so the union of all the nontrivial coset is open, so its complement (i.e. your subgroup) is closed.

You don't need to use Lie algebras or even assume your group is a Lie group.